# why does getdate returns 1\1\1900

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have the following code which does backward scheduling if Saturday or Sunday to move the date to Friday but why it returns `1900-01-06 00:00:00.000` rather `2017-03-31 13:18:12.300` i tried it getdate()-1 works fine which is Friday works great. I wounder why i doesn't work if Saturday or Sunday?

```
set datefirst 7 --Sunday

declare @ACUTBY datetime = getdate()

select 
case datepart(WEEKDAY, @ACUTBY)
    when 1 then 5
    when 7 then 5
    else  @ACUTBY
end as [A-CUT BY]
```

the above code `1900-01-06 00:00:00.000`

---- getdate()-1------

```
set datefirst 7 --Sunday

declare @ACUTBY datetime = getdate()-1

select 
case datepart(WEEKDAY, @ACUTBY)
    when 1 then 2
    when 7 then 5
    else  @ACUTBY
end as [A-CUT BY]
```

the above code return `2017-03-31 13:18:12.300`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `select Cast( 5 as DateTime )`.

You are mixing data types, e.g. an integer `5` and a datetime `@ACUTBY`, and the result of the `case` must be a single data type. Hence the numbers get converted to a `DateTime`. Since the base date for a `DateTime` is January 1st, 1900, adding `5` results in January 6th.

You might want something like:

```
declare @Samples as Table ( Sample Date );
insert into @Samples ( Sample ) values
  ( '20170402' ), ( '20170403' ), ( '20170404' ),
  ( '20170405' ), ( '20170406' ), ( '20170407' ), ( '20170408' );

select Sample, DatePart( dw, Sample ) as DoW,
  case DatePart( dw, Sample )
    when 1 then DateAdd( day, -2, Sample )
    when 7 then DateAdd( day, -1, Sample )
    else Sample end as WeekDay
  from @Samples;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to merge two different return values.

```
select 
case when datepart(WEEKDAY, @ACUTBY) = 1 then 2
     when datepart(WEEKDAY, @ACUTBY) = 7 then 5
     else datepart(WEEKDAY, @ACUTBY)
end as [A-CUT BY]
```

Comment: do you need a datetime or a day of week?